# How to convert SCSS nested @import to SASS format?

Tags: css, sass, converters, zurb-foundation

The Zurb Foundation framework has this information in the foundation.scss file. I want to convert this to a .sass file, but cannot figure out how to do this without a bunch of @import statements.

How would I translate this scss into sass without replicating @import on each line?

```
@import
  "foundation/components/global",
  "foundation/components/grid",
  "foundation/components/visibility",
  "foundation/components/block-grid",
  "foundation/components/type",
  "foundation/components/buttons",
  "foundation/components/forms",
  "foundation/components/button-groups",
  "foundation/components/dropdown-buttons",
  "foundation/components/split-buttons",
  "foundation/components/flex-video",
  "foundation/components/section",
  "foundation/components/top-bar",
  "foundation/components/orbit",
  "foundation/components/reveal",
  "foundation/components/joyride",
  "foundation/components/clearing",
  "foundation/components/alert-boxes",
  "foundation/components/breadcrumbs",
  "foundation/components/custom-forms",
  "foundation/components/keystrokes",
  "foundation/components/labels",
  "foundation/components/inline-lists",
  "foundation/components/pagination",
  "foundation/components/panels",
  "foundation/components/pricing-tables",
  "foundation/components/progress-bars",
  "foundation/components/side-nav",
  "foundation/components/sub-nav",
  "foundation/components/switch",
  "foundation/components/magellan",
  "foundation/components/tables",
  "foundation/components/thumbs",
  "foundation/components/tooltips",
  "foundation/components/dropdown";
```

Comment: Did you try using the `sass-convert` command (try `sass-convert --help` for more information)?  It is worth noting that you can work with the scss syntax and still be able to import files with the sass syntax (and vice versa).

Comment: Yeah. I got a bunch of @import statements which isn't what I'm goin' for.

Comment: What is wrong with a bunch of @import statements? It won't clutter any of the compiled code in the end, if that's your concern. I don't think that indented Sass syntax will allow anything else.

Comment: Code fold it if it's an eyesore, but there's not a lot else you can do unless you want to manually created one import which you copy/paste all of the above contents (in order) into one file then import the condensed file

Comment: Looks like you guys are right. No other way to do it. Seems Jade and Sass aren't as robust as CoffeeScript when it comes to utilizing multiple adjoined lines.